# Sending notification to Android device. Sent but not received

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I am getting familiar with sending notifications to devices,

I am currently trying to send a notification to my device using pubnub and Google cloud messaging:

```
(function() {
    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        subscribe_key: 'my-subscribe',
        publish_key:   'my-publish',
    });

    var os = 'android';
    var regid = '';
    var channel = 'mi-canal';
    
    function sendPush() {
        var gwtype = (os === 'ios') ? 'apns' : 'gcm';
        console.log('sending push notification...',channel,gwtype);

        pubnub.mobile_gw_provision({
            device_id: 'APA91bE0rX8mfzY0VttACffUPIagSbd5No0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxEHCVFBbzPqPHKG9phyQ31O4W6aEgMUqWANtWrK-zdMsiONUwAbUW4efso8ScemlXGM8tJq0M12oR0E2Kk9',
            channel: channel, 
            op: 'add', 
            gw_type: gwtype,
            error: function(msg){console.log(msg);},
            callback: function() {
                var message = PNmessage();

                message.pubnub = pubnub;
                message.callback = function (msg){ console.log(msg); };
                message.error = function (msg){ console.log(msg); };
                message.channel = channel;
                message.apns = {
                    alert: 'The room temperature is set too high'
                };
                message.gcm = {
                    title: 'PubNub Push Demo',
                    message: 'The room temperature is set too high'
                };

                message.publish();
            }            
        });

    }
    sendPush();
})();
```

Which logs:

`[1, "Sent", "14471821928645156"]`

the problem is that I don't receive the notification in the device, with and android app (cordova made)

```
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
            
            
            //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
            pushNotification.register(
                successHandler, 
                errorHandler, 
                {
                    'senderID':'api-project-xxxxxxxx',
                    'ecb':'onNotificationGCM' // callback function
                }
            );  
            pusNotification.subscribe({
                channel: 'mi-canal',
                message: function(m){
                    alert('Conslog: '+m);
                },
            error: function (error) {
              // Handle error here
              console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
            });
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Hi Toni! I see you are using `Cordova` and `Android` for you `HTML5` app.  You need to wait for the PubNub network system to allocate and provision the device GCM, I think that may be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) on my android app and it works like a charm.
You can read the documentation [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/phonegap-sdk-overview). It's 100% free and also uses Google's cloud messaging service. Basically after installing their SDK and following the entire documentation, your code will be something like this.

**Code example:**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  // Enable to debug issues.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});
  
  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };

  window.plugins.OneSignal.init("b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba",
                                 {googleProjectNumber: "703322744261"},
                                 notificationOpenedCallback);
  
  // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
  window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
}, false);
```

> - Replace "b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba" with your OneSignal App Id.
> - Replace "703322744261" with your Google Project Number.

To me, as soon as I send a notification it takes exactly 3 seconds till my phone gets a beep. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Interesting how quickly I got it running for android! the thing is I don't know how to target a user..?

Comment: Do you want to target a specific user to receive the notification only? Or do you want all of the users to receive the notification?

Comment: I want to get the user/device id when registers, so I can send him only the relevant to him..

Comment: There is an option called A/B tests inside your message's column at onesignal's website. I don't know if it'll work but I guess you can use the cordova-plugin-device in order to get the user's device model etc.. And then add the model inside the A/B test option. Do tell me if it works :p

Comment: I mean to identify the user and send only him a notification, kind of like this https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/phonegap--cordova-sdk-api#section-idsreceivedcallback

Comment: Go to segments and create a new one there and use the filter that you need.

Comment: Yes, but how to know the users id to include him?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94868/discussion-between-ray-joe-and-toni-michel-caubet).

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Cordova HTML5 on Android

> [Sending Android Push Notifications via GCM in JavaScript](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-18-sending-android-push-notifications-via-gcm-javascript-using-phonegap/)

Hi Toni! I see you are using `Cordova` and `Android` for you `HTML5` app.  You need to wait for the PubNub network system to allocate and provision the device for GCM. I think that may be the issue.  Just add a delay before sending GCM payload.  Also I added you a link to today's best guide on getting started with **GCM Push Notifications on Android using Cordova / PhoneGap**.

### Cordova GCM Push Notifications

You may be wondering if it’s possible to send Android push notifications from web apps written in JavaScript without setting up your own server. Well, it absolutely is when you combine the PubNub Push APIs with PhoneGap!

[image: GCM Cordova PhoneGap]

---

### Debugging Push Notifications

You can do some high level debugging using the channel's `-pndebug` channel and checking to see if the device is still registered to the channel.

#### pndebug channel

1. Use the [PubNub Dev Console](https://www.pubnub.com/console/) to subscribe to the channel's `-pndebug` channel. If the channel you are publishing to is `foo`, then subscribe to `foo-pndebug`. Make sure you use the right pub/sub keys.
2. Add `'pn_debug':true` to your message payload at the top level and publish that message.

   ```
   "pn_gcm": {
       "data": {
           "message": "hello"
       },
   }
   "pn_apns": {
       "aps": {
           "alert": "hello"
       },
   }
   "pn_debug": true
   ```
3. Publish the message to channel `foo`. You should see useful error messages in the Dev Console where you are subscribing to `foo-pndebug`, if there are any problems with the push message registration.

#### check channel registration

You can also check to see if the device is still registered to the channel after you publish the push notification using a simple REST URL in the browser.

`http://pubsub.pubnub.com/v1/push/sub-key/<your-sub-key>/devices/<device-reg-token>?type=gcm`

This will return all channels the device is still registered on for push notification (GCM in this case. Change `type` query param to `apns`, as required).

Returns: `["demo", "demo1", "demo2"]`

If the channel you just sent the push notification to is not in that list, then there was likely a device registration token issue (invalid token, or device not registered, for example). But the `-pndebug` channel should reveal this to you.

Comment: I apreciate your time! looks I'm not using pubnub after all.. thanks!